# How to set custom validation message in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to show my own message instead of one provided by the framework, So I did the following but it is not making any difference and showing default messages.

```
$message = [];
    foreach($request->get('estimates') as $key => $val)
    {
        $rules['estimates.'.$key] = 'required|integer';
        $message['estimates.'.$key] = 'Incorrect value';
    }
    $rules['technical_information'] = 'required';
    $rules['project_risks'] = 'required';

    $this->validate($request, $rules,$message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to adhere to the correct format for messages. Per the [Laravel docs:](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages)

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

The key in `$messages` needs to be the rule , and the value is the Message -- with a placeholder for the attribute name.

You can also specify messages per rule, per attribute by using dot syntax:

```
'username.required' => 'the field is required...'
```